# How to get the URL of form library item on another list

Tags: form

Scenario: User changes item in List A eg Field is flagged as SOLD for ItemA, this creates a form lib doc called SOLDItemA. Then the workflow will send an email sending to salesrep a link to that Form lib doc called SOLDItemA.

How do I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Construct a predictable URL. Also it will be good if you rephrase your example.